# Galaxy Tab and marker-based Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Well, I just bought the Samsung Galaxy Tab to do AR since it is a decent Android tablet with a rear camera and now I'm trying to get some marker-based AR on it and well.. it's fruitless :(

I tried the following:

- **AndAR project**: Getting errors with all 3 projects checked out from the SVN
- **NyARToolkit for the Android**: It runs so I can see the camera feed, but no augmentations occur.
- **Qualcomm SDK**: I was really looking forward to that one, until I found out that the Galaxy Tab is not in the supported devices' list! :'(

Has anyone ever managed to have marker-based AR on the Galaxy Tab ? If so, how did you manage to do so ?

Thank you!

f.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it... but u can try FLARToolkit... It's written using Flex... What u can do is write a Flex program and run it on Android AIR... I am currently working using FLARToolkit.

Comment: Thank you! I had no clue I could write Flex apps for the Android. I did some quick research online and it looks that it might be possible for FLARToolkit to work on the Tab! will try it soon, thanks again! f.

Comment: There is a wrapper around flartoolkit called FLARManager. It makes your job even simpler.